# user_login_finalize only works when the user has admin roles

Tags: hooks, authentication-authorization

i create custom login form in drupal 9 using user_login_finalize function. But this function only work when user has admin roles... i dont know why. This is my code :..

````
{
    if (isset($_POST['email']) && isset($_POST['password'])) {
        date_default_timezone_set("Asia/Jakarta");
        session_start();
        $session = new Session();

        $count_error = 0;
        $user = user_load_by_mail($_POST['email']);

        if (!$user) {
            $session->set('error_email', 'E-mail tidak sesuai');
            $count_error++;
        }

        if ($user) {
            if (!$user->isActive()) {
                $session->set('error_email', 'Akun kamu belum aktif');
                $count_error++;
            }

            $password_hasher = \Drupal::service('password');

            if (!$password_hasher->check($_POST['password'], $user->getPassword())) {
                $session->set('error_password', 'Password tidak sesuai');
                $count_error++;
            }
        }

        if ($count_error > 0) {
            $variables['error_email']       = $session->get('error_email');
            $variables['error_password']    = $session->get('error_password');
        }

        if ($count_error == 0 && $user) {
            user_login_finalize($user);
        }
    }
}```
````

Comment: What isn't working?

Comment: the function ```user_login_finalize```  only works when user has admin roles

Comment: And what is not happening?